# How can I get a TextBlock to literally say "{Binding}"?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, text, textblock

In XAML, if you insert

```
<TextBlock Text="Hello World" />
```

You will see the words "Hello World".

If you insert

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
```

it will trigger the data binding functionality. But what if I really wanted the display text to be "{Binding}"?"

Are there the equivalent of escape characters in XAML strings?

Or is my only solution to do this:

```
<TextBlock>Binding</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can escape the entire string with "{}":

```
<TextBlock Text="{}{Binding}"/>
```

Or individual curly braces can be escaped with a backslash:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Foo,StringFormat='Hello \{0\}'}" />
```

Answer (score 6):

Escaping with '{}' as per Matt's response is the way to go, but for the sake of completeness you can also use a CDATA section:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <![CDATA[{Binding}]]>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

A CDATA section is more useful for multiline text though.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<TextBlock Text="&#123;Binding&#125;" />
```

And unescape it when you read the value.

Comment: Oops, voted this up too soon. It works in the IDE display, but then I get a compile error. "The tag 'Binding;' does not exist in XML namespace 'schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/…'. "

Comment: Come to think of it, even I think escaping with a '\' makes more sense. Oh well, win some - lose some :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the { and } characters, so you'd end up with `<TextBlock Text="\{Binding\}" />`

Comment: That doesn't work. I tried it, and I saw the '\' characters in the display.